# Pitest is not finding my JUNIT tests on <targetTests> param

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration, pitest

I introduced the Pitest as a stage in our development schedule, but in one of the project it is not working and generating this info message:

Skipping project because:
[INFO]   - Project has no tests, it is empty.

Researching we found out could be something with the project structure: https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/361

POM with Pitest:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputFormats>
            <outputFormat>XML</outputFormat>
            <outputFormat>HTML</outputFormat>
        </outputFormats>
        <targetClasses>
            <!-- Update with your target classes/packages for mutation testing -->
            <param>br.com.company.project.operations</param>
        </targetClasses>
        <targetTests>
            <!-- Update with your test classes/packages -->
            <param>br.com.company.project.junit.tests</param>
        </targetTests>
        <exportLineCoverage>true</exportLineCoverage>
        <!--We want each report to override the former one-->
        <timestampedReports>false</timestampedReports>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pitest-mutation-testing</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Project Structure

```
├───CompanyProjectSaaS_Commons
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───module
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───commons
│   │                       ├───pojo
│   │                       └───utils
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   ├───br
│       │   │   └───com
│       │   │       └───company
│       │   │           └───project
│       │   │               └───commons
│       │   │                   ├───pojo
│       │   │                   └───utils
│       │   └───test
│       │       └───java
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───generated-test-sources
│       │   └───test-annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       ├───maven-status
│       │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
│       │       ├───compile
│       │       │   └───default-compile
│       │       └───testCompile
│       │           └───default-testCompile
│       ├───pit-reports
│       │   ├───202307041032
│       │   │   ├───br.com.company.project.commons.utils
│       │   │   └───br.com.company.project.commons.utils.test
│       │   ├───202307041034
│       │   │   ├───br.com.company.project.commons.utils
│       │   │   └───br.com.company.project.commons.utils.test
│       │   ├───202307041048
│       │   │   ├───br.com.company.project.commons.utils
│       │   │   └───br.com.company.project.commons.utils.test
│       │   ├───202307041103
│       │   │   ├───br.com.company.project.commons.utils
│       │   │   └───br.com.company.project.commons.utils.test
│       │   ├───202307041127
│       │   │   ├───br.com.company.project.commons.utils
│       │   │   └───br.com.company.project.commons.utils.test
│       │   ├───br.com.company.project.commons.utils
│       │   └───br.com.company.project.commons.utils.test
│       └───test-classes
│           └───test
│               └───java
├───CompanyProjectSaaS_Constants
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───module
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───constants
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───constants
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_Grpc
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main
│   │       ├───java
│   │       │   └───br
│   │       │       └───com
│   │       │           └───company
│   │       │               └───project
│   │       │                   └───grpc
│   │       └───resources
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───grpc
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_GrpcServer
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───server
│   │                       └───grpc
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───server
│       │                       └───grpc
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_JUnitTests
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───conf
│   ├───simulator
│   │   └───cryptoki_simulator
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       │   └───token
│   │       ├───admin.linux
│   │       │   └───token
│   │       └───slot0
│   │           └───token
│   ├───src
│   │   └───test
│   │       └───java
│   │           └───br
│   │               └───com
│   │                   └───company
│   │                       └───project
│   │                           └───junit
│   │                               └───tests
│   │                                   └───utils
│   └───target
│       ├───generated-test-sources
│       │   └───test-annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       ├───maven-status
│       │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
│       │       └───testCompile
│       │           └───default-testCompile
│       ├───surefire-reports
│       └───test-classes
│           ├───br
│           │   └───com
│           │       └───company
│           │           └───project
│           │               ├───commons
│           │               │   └───utils
│           │               └───junit
│           │                   └───tests
│           │                       └───utils
│           └───test
│               └───java
│                   ├───br
│                   │   └───com
│                   │       └───company
│                   │           └───project
│                   │               └───junit
│                   │                   └───tests
│                   ├───commons
│                   │   └───utils
│                   └───junit
│                       └───tests
│                           └───utils
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_Logger
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───module
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───logger
│   │                       ├───pojo
│   │                       ├───report
│   │                       └───utils
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───logger
│       │                       ├───pojo
│       │                       ├───report
│       │                       └───utils
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_PKCS11
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───pkcs11
│   │                       ├───devices
│   │                       ├───support
│   │                       ├───token
│   │                       │   └───asn1
│   │                       └───utils
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───pkcs11
│       │                       ├───devices
│       │                       ├───support
│       │                       ├───token
│       │                       │   └───asn1
│       │                       └───utils
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_PKCS11SunWrapper
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───bin
│   │   └───sun
│   │       └───security
│   │           └───pkcs11
│   ├───module
│   ├───src
│   │   ├───jdk
│   │   │   └───internal
│   │   │       ├───misc
│   │   │       ├───ref
│   │   │       └───util
│   │   └───sun
│   │       ├───net
│   │       │   └───www
│   │       ├───nio
│   │       │   ├───ch
│   │       │   └───cs
│   │       ├───security
│   │       │   ├───action
│   │       │   ├───internal
│   │       │   │   ├───interfaces
│   │       │   │   └───spec
│   │       │   ├───jca
│   │       │   ├───pkcs
│   │       │   ├───pkcs11
│   │       │   │   └───wrapper
│   │       │   ├───provider
│   │       │   ├───rsa
│   │       │   ├───util
│   │       │   └───x509
│   │       └───util
│   │           └───calendar
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   ├───jdk
│       │   │   └───internal
│       │   │       ├───misc
│       │   │       ├───ref
│       │   │       └───util
│       │   └───sun
│       │       ├───net
│       │       │   └───www
│       │       ├───nio
│       │       │   ├───ch
│       │       │   └───cs
│       │       ├───security
│       │       │   ├───action
│       │       │   ├───internal
│       │       │   │   ├───interfaces
│       │       │   │   └───spec
│       │       │   ├───jca
│       │       │   ├───pkcs
│       │       │   ├───pkcs11
│       │       │   │   └───wrapper
│       │       │   ├───provider
│       │       │   ├───rsa
│       │       │   ├───util
│       │       │   └───x509
│       │       └───util
│       │           └───calendar
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_PKCS11Wrapper
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───pkcs11
│   │                       └───wrapper
│   │                           └───sun
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───pkcs11
│       │                       └───wrapper
│       │                           └───sun
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyProjectSaaS_Processor
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───server
│   │                       └───processor
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───server
│       │                       └───processor
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_Processors_Builder
│   ├───.settings
│   └───target
│       └───antrun
├───CompanyprojectSaaS_Processor_Example
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   ├───operations
│   │                   │   └───jwedecrypt
│   │                   └───processor
│   │                       └───jwedecrypt
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   ├───operations
│       │                   │   └───jwedecrypt
│       │                   └───processor
│       │                       └───jwedecrypt
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile

[...] 

## There is a lot of this Processors, the structure are always the same as above.

[...]

├───CompanyprojectSaaS_RestServer
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───server
│   │                       └───rest
│   │                           ├───controller
│   │                           └───services
│   └───target
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───server
│       │                       └───rest
│       │                           ├───controller
│       │                           └───services
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
├───CompanyProjectSaaS_Server
│   ├───.settings
│   ├───config
│   ├───logs
│   │   └───history
│   ├───processors
│   ├───src
│   │   └───br
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───company
│   │               └───project
│   │                   └───server
│   └───target
│       ├───antrun
│       ├───classes
│       │   └───br
│       │       └───com
│       │           └───company
│       │               └───project
│       │                   └───server
│       ├───generated-sources
│       │   └───annotations
│       ├───maven-archiver
│       └───maven-status
│           └───maven-compiler-plugin
│               └───compile
│                   └───default-compile
└───CompanyProjectSaaS_Server_Builder
    ├───.settings
    ├───build
    │   ├───Depends
    │   │   ├───docs
    │   │   └───company_project
    │   │       ├───config
    │   │       ├───linux
    │   │       ├───processors
    │   │       └───windows
    │   │           ├───x64
    │   │           └───x86
    │   ├───installer_files
    │   └───installer_out
    ├───dist
    └───target
        └───antrun
```

I tried to change the project structure and to add * in the target, but none of them worked. I was able to create a pitest for a test and source code that doesn't follow this structure.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you have tests in a seperate module from the code. Pitest does not support this.

Comment: Yes, the tests are separated. To put they together will be so much time consuming, and problematic (because of configuration to use a simultor and etc). Do you see any form to fix it or is there a plan to add this feature?